# How to get a longer underscore without using T1 encoding

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

I am creating a new LaTeX document in TeXStudio using the default font encoding. I have noticed that the _ character looks extremely short in this font. `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` solves this problem, but it also makes all of the words look pixelated/blurry compared to the standard font. Is there a way to get the best of both worlds?

Comment: You can use `\rule{10mm}{1pt}` with the wanted arguments

Comment: TeXStudio is just one of many available front-ends to a TeX distributiion. Please tell us which TeX distribution (MikTeX? TeXllive? something else?) you use. Please also tell us what "the standard font" is; is it Computer Modern? Please also tell us how you compile your LaTeX documents. Do you use pdfLaTeX to create a pdf file, or do you use some other compile sequence, e.g., via dvi and ps stages?

Comment: Install the cm-super fonts to get non pixelated fonts with T1 or use the package lmodern.

Comment: unless you are writing in English you should use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` otherwise hyphenation will be incorrect in your document. If you are getting pixelated fonts than that is fixable you just have to install the fonts.

Comment: @Mico I am using MikTeX. I just use pdfLaTeX to create a pdf file.